# What is the new use for bonemeal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the [new use for bonemeal](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/6035819427/minecraft-beta-1-6-6) mentioned in the 1.6.6 patch notes?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Using it on grass with enough space will cause long grass and flowers to appear.
[image: Before bone meal]

[image: After bone meal]

You can also use the bone meal on the underside of the block and long grass will still grow.

Comment: it also has a chance to spawn flowers as well, as shown by the screen shot.

Comment: Doesn't it make tree saplings instantly grow too?

Comment: @danixd It does (and wheat) but that is not the 'new' use for it introduced in 1.6.6

Comment: @GSto It does and always has said that in the answer.

Comment: @James my bad, didn't notice the emphasis on new. (I didn't know this about wheat either, thanks!)

Comment: Thank you for putting this in a format that isn't YouTube. It's extremely appreciated (not to mention simpler).

Answer (score 1):

The function of bonemeal and grass has not changed in the 7 months between 1.6.6 and 1.0.1.

It will still give you long grass and flowers. The former is likely to become important since sheep will be able to eat it next patch to regrow their wool.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: I thought sheep ate short grass?

Comment: ["As of week 49 snapshot sheep can now regrow wool by eating grass turning the grass block into a dirt block."](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Sheep)

Comment: @John - from [Mojang's Website](http://mojang.com/2011/12/15/minecraft-dev-snapshot-week-50/) : `For the record: Currently Sheep eat both grass from grass blocks and from tallgrass. They will eat grass regardless if they have been sheared or not, but baby sheep will eat more often than old sheep.`